# On merging Excel and Tex files

Tags: tables, formatting, excel

I am doing some teaching and need some help to make the process of page-proof faster. For the last exam participants are given a piece of paper of the following format:

Name Surname

some info

*and then a **table** with tasks in the following format (there are **a few** of them)*

number of task|text|score

The problem is that for every person the set of tasks is different and the number of tasks is also not the same for everybody.

The list of participants is in Excel, their tasks are in another Tex file. Is there an easy way to generate file of the given format, taking names from Excel and tasks from Tex?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the `datatool` package.

Comment: @AlanMunn where can I get more info on this package? More like tutorial, not just documentation would be really appreciated

Comment: If you look at the documentation for it, it is excellent, and has 46 examples of various sorts. There are also quite a few worked out examples of its use here on the site (just choose the `datatool` tag) and browse there.

Comment: @AlanMunn thx, I'll search it, though it is not gonna be fast, it has 225 pages in it

Comment: I'm sorry but no documentation can solve any one individual's problem. And you'd complain more if the documentation were very terse. The `datatool` manual is good, and as I said if you look on the site there are plenty of worked out example documents.  Look for the things you need to do, try some simple examples and see how it goes.

Comment: In addition to the `datatool` documentation, there's also [Managing Data](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/datatool.shtml) which includes accessing data from external files.